# What are WEBGPU workgroup_size limits?

Tags: compute-shader, webgpu

I have simple compute shader like:

```
@compute @workgroup_size(x, y, z)
fn main(@builtin(global_invocation_id) global_id : vec3<u32>) {
    ...
}
```

where `x`, `y` and `z` are some integers. But I suppose the size of a data, I want to handle will be super large. So what is the maximum value I can specify for `x`, `y` and `z`? If it is system-dependent, so how I can determine it programmatically? How can I handle data, that is out of these limits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum values are listed in the [spec](https://gpuweb.github.io/gpuweb/#dom-supported-limits-maxcomputeworkgroupsizex) with:

- Maximum X - 256
- Maximum Y - 256
- Maximum Z - 64

With an overall maximum of (X * Y * Z of 65535)

Comment: You may have misunderstood spec, `WorkgroupSize` and `maxComputeWorkgroupsPerDimension` are two different parameters. `maxComputeWorkgroupsPerDimension` (its value is 65535) is the maximum value for the arguments of `cpass.dispatchWorkgroups(...)`, and `WorkgroupSizeX * Y * Z` must  be <= 256 ([`maxComputeInvocationsPerWorkgroup`](https://gpuweb.github.io/gpuweb/#dom-supported-limits-maxcomputeinvocationsperworkgroup))